# Ajax submit form with jquery not validating

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

could you please help me with the code above?

I', trying to have some validation in there but the validation is not being executed and the form is submitted without the validation:

HTML:

```
              <form method="post" action="" id="subscription-form">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="subscribe-email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="youremail@example.com" required>
                  <p><span class="error-message">Please enter a valid email</span></p>
                </div>
                <button id="" class="" type="submit"><span>Subscribe</span></button>
              </form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#subscription-form').on('submit', function (e) {

      var form = $(this);
      var regexEmail = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      var url = "https://mycustomapi.net";

      if (!$('.subscribe-email').val().match(regexEmail)) {
        $('.error-message').hide();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: form.serialize(),
          success: function (data) {
            $('#subscribed-error').hide()
            $('#subscribed-feedback').show()
            $('#subscription-form').hide()
          },
          error: function () {
            $('#subscribed-error').show()
            $('#subscribed-feedback').hide()
            $('#subscription-form').show()
          }
        });
        console.log('email submitted');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
      else {
        $('.error-message').show();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    });

  });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error was the ! operator

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#subscription-form').on('submit', function (e) {

      var form = $(this);
      var regexEmail = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/g;
      var url = "https://mycustomapi.net";

      if ($('.subscribe-email').val().match(regexEmail)) {
        $('.error-message').hide();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: form.serialize(),
          success: function (data) {
            $('#subscribed-error').hide()
            $('#subscribed-feedback').show()
            $('#subscription-form').hide()
          },
          error: function () {
            $('#subscribed-error').show()
            $('#subscribed-feedback').hide()
            $('#subscription-form').show()
          }
        });
        console.log('email submitted');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
      else {
       console.log("not submitted");
        $('.error-message').show();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }});
});
```

```html
<form method="post" action="" id="subscription-form">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="subscribe-email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="youremail@example.com" required>
                  <p><span class="error-message">Please enter a valid email</span></p>
                </div>
                <button id="" class="" type="submit"><span>Subscribe</span></button>
              </form>
```

Comment: Yes, ! was the major issue, but even after fixing that, error message will not appear. All the selectors in jquery are using ID selector i.e. '#' and DOM has all the classes,so selector needs to be the class one 'dot' and not '#'

Comment: Thanks for your reply xKurisu. @DM, even after these changes (! operator and "#" to "." the show on "errormessage" ($('.error-message').show();) didn't work

Comment: Done removed the !important here: #error-message{
  display: none;